# module not fond when call Lua file in ios

Tags: ios, lua

i am writing an ios game.i use lua to write the game logic.then i try to integrate lua files into ios program.i add the lua files to app resource.when i run the program, an error occur:

```
LUA_ERRRUN: a runtime error.
...4-489C-4A40-8582-F734FAAC428D/ChemLLK.app/llk_facade.lua:3: module 'lianliankan' not found:
no field package.preload['lianliankan']
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lianliankan.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lianliankan/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lianliankan.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lianliankan/init.lua'
no file './lianliankan.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lianliankan.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
no file './lianliankan.so'
```

i wander whether "." in path is equal to the resource folder. and i don't know how to solve this problem.
who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a script calls `require`, it searches a number of preset locations for the script. None of those preset locations are your application *resources*. Therefore, a script's `require` function will never find what it's looking for.

You need to register a handler for `require` that will look for the script in your resources.